# Using OpenCV with DevCPP

Tags: opencv, dev-c++

I am a newbie to OpenCV and I am trying to use it with DevC++. Although I am aware I could use Visual Studio for the same , I would still like to use DevC++.

The OpenCV Wiki-how seems obsolete with this information. Can you please tell me the steps with which I can modify the Compiler Options in DevCpp so that I may kick-off with OpenCV.

Any help is highly appreciated ...

Also, OpenCV wiki directs me to paste the following code in the Compiler Options ,

`-L"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\lib" -lcxcore -lcv -lcvaux -lhighgui -lml -lcvcam`

Sadly , I did not find the `lib` folder in my OpenCV directory..

Comment: maybe build/x86/mingw/lib?

Comment: The `build/x86/mingw/lib` does not contain any of the cxcore , cv files ...